# Why is Scala's Type system not a Library in Clojure

Tags: scala, clojure

I've heard people claim that:

- Scala's type system is amazing (existential types, variant, co-variant)
- Because of the power of macros, everything is a library in Clojure: (pattern matching, logic programming, non-determinism, ..)

Question:

If both assertions are true, why is Scala's type system not a library in Clojure? Is it because:

- types are one of these things that do not work well as a library? [i.e. the changes would somehow have to threaded through every existing clojure library, including clojure.core?]
- is Scala's notion of types fundamentally incompatible with clojure protocol / records?
- ... ?

Comment: @Ankur: I believe Scalar's Type System :: Haskell's type system == Clojure :: Scheme . It lost some of the purity, but solves numerous practical problems.

Comment: I am not sure if this is even feasible to implement a static type system in a dynamic type system language

Comment: @Ankur: here is a prototype https://github.com/frenchy64/typed-clojure

Comment: That is a type checker and not a type system in itself.

Comment: @user1311390 keep in mind that Typed Clojure and Typed Racket are a way less powerful than Haskell or Scala type system. And it is ok, it is almost impossible to reach the same level of expressiveness in type system that was not designed as a part of a language from the very beginning.

Comment: @Ankur: how do you distinguish type checker form type system? I view Haskell as a glorified type checker, yet most would call it a type system.

Comment: For the record, I think that those projects are beautiful. What I mean by notion of powerity above: "which terms we can assign types to", "can we not repeat redundant types".

Comment: @S.Kucherenko: I've always had this (highly biased) belief that type systems were really meant to be turing-complete languages with crappy syntax. Example: C++ templates. And in this regard, I've (probably naively) believed that since Clojure macros are Clojure code; if only Clojure had a type system, it'd have the worlds most flexible type system. (Perhaps this statement is vacuously true given Clojure is dynamically typed.)

Comment: @user1311390 Type system is formal abstraction describing types behavior and restrictions, and type checker is a concrete implementation of the type system. For example, Haskell type system is System F with some extensions (a formal mathematical construction), and type checker is a part of compiler, which can vary across Haskell implementations (GHC, Hugs, YHC etc). It is difficult to develop sound type system for impure and dynamic language, consequently, writing powerful type checker is difficult too. Because of this language support for type system is required.

Comment: By "concrete implementation of type system" I mean a program which check types of expressions using the rules defined by the type system. So, if these rules are vague or incomplete (mostly), useful type checking is not possible.

Comment: @Vladimir: Can I summarize your comment as: "type system" = spec; "type checker" = implementation ? This makes sense. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @user1311390 I guess you can, but only if you define "spec" correctly :) It may seem that I wrote about formal type systems which are mathematical theories, but this is not so. Every language has a type system because some kind of types are present in *every* language. Some languages choose to check types at compile time, some - at runtime, some - never at all (e.g. assembler), but usually the earlier type checking is performed, the stronger the type system is.

Comment: By "strength" of the type system I understand the amount of metainformation about variables and expressions which compiler is able to get. In those type systems which are formal theories, like System F or even Calculus of Constructions (Agda2, Coq), the guarantees about types are so strong that it is possible to prove that the value of given expression will always be in the boundaries of statically known range. This essentially eliminates all but the logical errors, and even some logical errors too, given that the program typechecks and compiles.

Comment: OTOH, weak type systems like in Python usually do not provide any information about expressions. The exact type of the expression become known only when this expression is evaluated. Such systems are much more easier to implement and program with, but they do not have strong guarantees, and the languages based on such systems are subjects to runtime errors, when some operation is applied to a value of incompatible type.

Comment: Clojure compiler is able to extract some information about types from the source code. It is possible to write completely dynamic system using reflection everywhere, but the code produced by such compiler will be very slow. Clojure does a good job in finding expression types, and you can use type hints to direct it if needed, but it is impossible to make Clojure use strong type system without turning it into completely different language.

Comment: Scala have macro system too: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O879Iz-567FzVb8kw6N5OBpei9dnbW0ZaT7-XNSa6Cs/edit?pli=1

Answer (score 12):

It's an interesting question.

You are certainly right about Scala having an amazing type system, and about Clojure being phenomenal for meta-programming and extension of the language (although that is about more than just macros....).

A few reasons I can think of:

1. Clojure is a dynamically typed language while Scala is a statically typed language. Having powerful type inference isn't so much use in a language where you can assume relatively little about the types of your inputs.
2. Clojure already has a very interesting project to add typing as a library ([Typed Clojure](https://github.com/frenchy64/typed-clojure)) which looks very promising - however it's very different in approach to Scala as it is designed for a dynamic language from the start (inspired more by [Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/), I believe).
3. Clojure philosophy actually discourages certain OOP concepts (particularly implementation inheritance, mutable objects, and data encapsulation). A type system that supports these things (as Scala does) wouldn't be a good fit for Clojure idioms - at best they would be ignored, but they could easily encourage a style of development that would cause people to run into severe problems later.
4. Clojure already provides tools that solve many of the problems you would typically solve with types in other languages - e.g. the use of protocols for polymorphism.
5. There's a strong focus in the Clojure community on simplicity (in the sense of the excellent video ["Simple Made Easy"](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Simple-Made-Easy/) - see particularly the slide at 39:30). While Scala's type system is certainly amazing, I think it's a stretch to describe it as "Simple"
6. Putting in a Scala-style type system would probably require a complete rewrite of the Clojure compiler and make it substantially more complex. Nobody seems to have signed up so far to take on that particular challenge... and there's a risk that even if someone were willing and able to do this then the changes could be rejected for the various cultural / technical reasons covered above.

In the absence of a major change to Clojure itself (which I think would be unlikely) then one interesting possibility would be to create a DSL within Clojure that provided Scala-style type inference for a specific domain and compiled this DSL direct to optimised Java bytecode. I could see that being a useful approach for specific problem domains (large scale numerical data crunching with big matrices, for example).

Comment: do you mind if I change bulleted list into numbered list so it's easier to reference your points?

Comment: No particular objection, though they are of type "unordered list". Assume order at your peril :-)

Answer (score 5):

To simply answer your question "... why is Scala's type system not a library in Clojure?":

Because the type system is part of the scala compiler and not of the scala library. The whole power of scalas type system only exists at compile time. The JVM has no support for things like that, because of type erasure and also, because it would simply slow down execution. And also there is no need for it. If you have a statically typed language, you don't need type information at runtime, unless you want to do dirty stuff.

edit:

@mikera the jvm is sure capable of running the scala compiler, I did not say anything like that. I just said, that the jvm has no support for type systems like that. It does not even support generics. At runtime all these types are gone. The compiler checks for the correctness of a program and removes all the higher kinded types / generics.

example:

```
val xs: List[Int] = List(1,2,3,4)
val x1: Int = xs.head
```

will at runtime look like this:

```
val xs: List = List.apply(1,2,3,4)
val x1: Int = xs.head.asInstanceOf[Int]
```

But it doesn't matter, because the compiler checked it before. You can only get in trouble here, when you use reflection, because you could put any value in the list and it would break at runtime exactly where the value is casted to `Int`.

And this is one of the reasons, why the scala type system is not part of the scala library, but built into the compiler.

And also the question of the OP was "... why is Scala's type system not a library in Clojure?" and not "Is it possible to create a type system such as scalas for clojure?" and I perfectly answered that question.

Comment: The JVM is perfectly capable of running a compiler with a Scala-style type system. Scala itself couldn't exist if this wasn't possible, since Scala's compiler (as well as the code after it is compiled) runs on the JVM!